# Why are added Object Properties not traversing down?

Tags: javascript

```
Object.someProp = "hello";
Object.prototype.somProp2 = "hello2";
var i = new Object();
alert(i.somProp2);//1
alert(i.someProp);//2
```

why does 1 work but not 2?
If almost every object is derived from "Object", shouldn't someProp traverse down the chain same way as someProp2. I am new to this, so any help is good?

Comment: Object instances inherit from *Object.prototype*, not *Object*. `i.someProp` should return *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}
Person.prototype.nationality = "English";
Person.nationality2 = "English";

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"My father is " + myFather.nationality + myFather.nationality2;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

if you run this it will show you My father is Englishundefined

but if u run this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}
Person.prototype.nationality = "English";

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"My father is " + myFather.nationality;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the out put is My father is English

so the The JavaScript prototype property allows you to add new properties to an existing prototype:
 JavaScript function has a prototype property (this property is empty by default), and you attach properties and methods on this prototype property when you want to implement inheritance